# Replacing a consecutive single and double quote using .replace?

Tags: python

I the following `.replace` statement I have an issue in that I am trying to replace a consecutive single and double quotation in a string:

```
mystring.replace(''"', '"')
```

That doesn't seem to work though, I suspect because I am wrapping the string to be replaced also in single quotes. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `'` will be considered to be the closing quote, escape it using a `\` to consider it in.

**replace**

```
mystring.replace(''"', '"')
```

**with**

```
mystring.replace('\'"', '"');
```

Comment: ah right. i wasn't sure if you could use escape characters in a .replace statement. thanks.

Comment: Any string can have an escape character.

Comment: @UmaKanth except row stings starting with r'...'.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quote:

```
mystring.replace('\'"', '"')
```